# Delegate on Delegate

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, segue

I have a situation: I have a SideMenu and there is a Logout button on it.
After the logout is triggered, 2 things are to be done:

1. `try Auth.auth().signOut()` is to be done in Firebase
2. `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` is to be triggered

On the screenshot below (I will add description for those, who cannot see) I show the flow:

1. Initial Controller; Class in storyboard - Empty
   leads to (segue has no name)
2. Welcome Controller; Class in storyboard - WelcomeController (script)
   leads to (segue has no name)
3. Menu Navigation Controller; Class in storyboard - empry
   leads to (segue has no name)
4. New Main Controller; Class in storyboard - NewMainController
   leads to (segue has a name - burgerSegue)
5. Side Navigation Controller (from pods SideMenu); Class in storyboard - SideNavigationController (as in documentation + module = SideMenu)
   leads to (segue has no name)
6. ViewController (where I store my SideMenu); Class in storyboard - empty
   leads to (segue has a name - finalSegueToMenu)
7. Menu Controller; Class in storyboard - SideMenuButtons (script)

Ideally, I was trying to connect NewMainController and MenuController with delegates.

This is what I had in MenuController:

```
    @IBAction func logoutClicked(_ sender: Any) 
    {
        if delegate == nil {
            print("Delegate is nil")
        } else {
            print("Delegate is set")
            delegate?.logoutClickedInSideMenu()
        }

        print("Logout button clicked")
    }
```

Yet, each time I got **Delegate is nil**.

Could it be that my whole approach is wrong and there is a simpler option?

Important: SideMenu is created in Storyboard, not in programmatically.

Thanks!

[image: 1) Initial Controller; Class in storyboard - Empty leads to (segue has no name) 2) Welcome Controller; Class in storyboard - WelcomeController (script) leads to (segue has no name) 3) Menu Navigation Controller; Class in storyboard - empry leads to (segue has no name) 4) New Main Controller; Class in storyboard - NewMainController leads to (segue has a name - burgerSegue) 5) Side Navigation Controller (from pods SideMenu); Class in storyboard - SideNavigationController (as in documentation + module = SideMenu) leads to (segue has no name) 6) ViewController (where I store my SideMenu); Class in storyboard - empty leads to (segue has a name - finalSegueToMenu) 7) Menu Controller; Class in storyboard - SideMenuButtons (script)]

Comment: Unrelated to the question but **one** line `delegate?.logoutClickedInSideMenu()` is sufficient. It doesn't call the method if `delegate` is `nil` due to *Optional Chaining*. The reason of the issue might be a *custom* instance of one of the view controllers. Show the code where you set the delegate.

Comment: attach delegate whenever `MenuController` will open

Comment: @vadian yes-yes. It was done for debugging purposes.

Comment: @OmSanatan, but that's the question: from which script should I do it? So each time Menu is opened, it should add a delegate? I don't get it. Menu is opened when the BurgerMenu is clicked => it is not created programmatically. So it means, I need to attach the delegate only once...